# Show name of country in Views summary when using Countries module

Tags: views

I am using the [Countries](http://drupal.org/project/countries) module (7.x-2.0-beta2) with Drupal 7.12. A Country field is part of a node and a View of all these nodes looks like this:

Place1     United States
Place2     Mexico
Place3     United States
Place4     Canada
Place5     Mexico

The Views summary, with Country field as contextual filter/argument results in the following:

CA (1)
MX (2)
US (2)

I want to get the default or full country name rather than 2-character ISO country code in the summary, but have not managed that despite trying different country field configurations.

I have Googled and not been able fo find a solution. Note that I am using the Countries module, not the Location module. Location:Countries works fine, but I am migrating from Location to Geofield.

Is there a way to obtain the country name instead of country code in the summary?  Preferably without writing code, but I will take all solutions. Thanks.